# How should I code a javascript function so I can call it from a link?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a style switcher. What I would like to do is to have some boxes on my page for each color. Something like the following:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" Title="Style A" onclick="javascript:changeStyle("/Content/Themes-jQuery/humanity/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css")>A</td>
<td><a href="#" Title="Style B" onclick="javascript:changeStyle("/Content/Themes-jQuery/vader/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css")>B</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then within the function I would like to do this:

```
$("link[title='jquery-ui-theme']").attr("href", xxx  );
```

Where xxx is the argument passed to the function.

Can someone give me some advice on how I can call the function from inside the `<a>` link and what the definition of the function would need to look like.

Also is there a better way that I could do this using more jQuery? Would it be better to use DIVs instead of table/rows?

Comment: I think you want to avoid using onclick. Try moving that into your jquery function.

Comment: You are using jQuery but then adding inline onclick attributes. That can work, but is somewhat contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way you could do it. For example, you could use this markup:

```
<ul class="style-switcher">
    <li><a href="#" data-style="humanity">Humanity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-style="vader">Vader</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
$(".style-switcher").on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var style = $(this).attr('data-style');
    changeStyle('/Content/Themes-jQuery/' + style + '/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

To make it look the same, you could use this CSS:

```
.style-switcher {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.style-switcher > li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 10em; /* You should probably adjust this. */
}
.style-switcher > li > a {
    display: block;
    width: 10em; /* You should probably adjust this. */
}
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXh5t/) on JSFiddle.**

What could make it even better is to change the `href` to some location that would make style switching work for users with scripts disabled.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be cleaner if you did it this way:

```
<table id="themes">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/Content/Themes-jQuery/humanity/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" Title="Style A">A</td>
        <td><a href="/Content/Themes-jQuery/vader/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" Title="Style B" >B</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#themes a').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("link[title='jquery-ui-theme']").attr("href", $(this).attr('href') );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: All the themes are different only by the directory name. In this case the directory names are humanity or vader. Would it be possible for me to remove the need for the href and just use the Title as the key. I guess I would need to add the "/Content/Themes-jQuery/" then the title and then "/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css"

Comment: Definitely, you can use $(this).attr('title')

Comment: Is this really cleaner?  If they have JavaScript turned off it will have a negative effect rather than no effect.

Comment: If they have javascript turned off they can still access the CSS sheets.  Wouldn't call that a negative

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do that:

```
$('a.clickme').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('style'));
});
```

And your links layout would look like:

```
<a href="#" Title="Style A" class="clickme" data-style="humanity">A</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GtcP6/

Answer (score 1):

When using `onlcick`, you don't need to say `javascript:` - that's only for use in `href`.

Otherwise, it should work.  Just remember to escape your quotes if using the same ones as your html attribute.

E.g.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" Title="Style A" onclick="changeStyle(\"/Content/Themes-jQuery/humanity/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css\")">A</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" Title="Style B" onclick="changeStyle(\"/Content/Themes-jQuery/vader/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css\")">B</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or for a cleaner look, just use single quotes:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:changeStyle('/Content/Themes-jQuery/humanity/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css')" Title="Style A">A</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:changeStyle('/Content/Themes-jQuery/vader/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css')" Title="Style B">B</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Or some variation thereof.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

**jQuery**:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("link[title='jquery-ui-theme']").attr("href", $(this).attr('rel') );
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" Title="Style A" rel="/Content/Themes-jQuery/humanity/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">A</td>
<td><a href="#" Title="Style B" rel="/Content/Themes-jQuery/vader/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">B</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This removes the inline events. Also, your divs vs table rows question seems unrelated to the jQuery part of your question. How you layout your links depends more on how they will be used by the visitor.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely *want* to use `onclick`, at least quote properly. You're mixing double quotes and single quotes. Try this:

```
onclick="javascript:changeStyle('/Content/Themes-jQuery/humanity/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css')"
```

A better approach, however, would be to offload this to jQuery entirely:

```
$('tr a.switchstyle').click(function() {
  changeStyle('/Content/Themes-jQuery/' + $(this).attr('title') + '/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css');
});
```

And set the `title` attribute of each link:

```
<a href="#" title="humanity">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler approach...

Link both of them at the top and then use:

```
<a onclick="this.className='selected1'" href="#">Test 1</a>
<a onclick="this.className='selected2'" href="#">Test 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple technique & effective for future use-

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="changeTheme" rel="themeA">Swith Theme A</a>
<p/>
<a href="#" class="changeTheme" rel="themeB">Swith Theme B</a>
<p/>
<a href="#" class="changeTheme" rel="themeD">Swith Default Theme</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(".changeTheme").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $changeTo = $(this).attr("rel");
    switch($changeTo)
    {
        case 'themeA':  $cssURL = "css/themeA.css";
                        break;
        case 'themeB':  $cssURL = "css/themeB.css";
                        break;
        default:        $cssURL = "css/themeD.css";
                        break;
    }
    $("link[title='pageTheme']").attr("href", $cssURL);
});
```